# How to sort records by distance using Algolia?

Tags: sorting, distance, algolia

Using Algolia Search, I’m trying sort my records by distance without filtering them by a radius but I fail to do so. I can successfully filter by a radius by setting `aroundLatLng` and `aroundRadius` in my query. But records are not sorted in the result. According to [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/#:%7E:text=Ranking%20effect%3A%20Radius%2Dbased%20filtering%20creates%20a%20circle%20within%20which%20all%20results%20fall.%20It%20also%20creates%20a%20ranking%20based%20on%20the%20distance%20from%20that%20point%20%2D%20records%20closest%20to%20the%20central%20point%20are%20ranked%20higher%20than%20records%20further%20away.) part of Algolia's documentation, a ranking is created based on the distance from the central point. So, records must be sorted by distance if there aren't any sorting in the query. According to [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/#:%7E:text=Sorting%20by%20distance,a%20provided%20point.), to sort by distance without filtering, one needs to set `aroundRadius` to `"all"`. I've tried setting `aroundRadius` to `"all"` but it didn't change anything.

Also in [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/#:%7E:text=in%20the%20results.-,Geo,properties.,-Changing%20precision) part of the docs, it’s stated that geo criterion must be present in the ranking formula to sort by distance and I confirmed that it is present. So what could be the problem here? Any help would be appreciated. Note that there is location info in every record with the key `"_geoloc"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the default ranking criteria did not exist. In Ranking and Sorting section of my index, I've reset settings to default and the default ranking criteria appeared. After that, I've been able sort records by distance. Below is a screenshot that shows the Ranking and Sorting section after resetting settings to default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If filtering is working as expected for `aroundLatLng`, then it's safe to assume you have the `_geoloc` data populated appropriately for your records.

Since you want to sort by geo proximity, this sounds like a ranking issue.

I'm unfamiliar with setting `aroundRadius` to `"all"` -- the engine will need a lat/long to compare distances for the ranking, so you'll need a specific set of coordinates for the search (that's why geo ranking doesn't work for area searches `insideBoundingBox`).

If you're supplying specific coordinates in `aroundLatLng` and still not getting the geo ranking you expect (and you've confirmed `geo` is a ranking criteria) -- is it possible the default precision of 10 meters doesn't work well with your data set? Maybe [tweaking the precision](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/in-depth/geo-ranking-precision/) would help here?

If sort/ranking config and geo precision aren't the problem, I would recommend adding `getRankingInfo=true` to your query. This will return all of the ranking criteria evaluated against each record -- you can confirm that the index took `_geoloc` into account.

If none of this helps -- maybe drop me your index configuration and the query you're executing so I can dig in further.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/how-to/geo-ranking-info/

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/#sorting-by-distance) part of the docs for more info on setting aroundRadius to `"all"`. I'm always providing a lat-long to reference in ranking. There's a record that is closer than 10 km to the lat-long I provide. When I set the aroundRadius to 10 km, I only get that record. This means it's the closest record. When I provide `"all"` to aroundRadius, I should see that record comes first in results since it's the closest one but I don't.

Comment: What do you mean by index configuration? How can I provide that information to you?